# How to know and change Swift version when compiled Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode

I am using the same Xcode to build a .framework file and a new Swift project. However, after successfully building the .framework file and incorporating it into the new project, I received the following error message: "Module compiled with Swift 5.2.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.8.1 compiler." I am puzzled about how to accurately determine the Swift version I used when compiling that .framework file and why there is this discrepancy.

[image]